# Cursor color in TexShop

Tags: texshop

I have not found this question in the forum: how can I change the colour of the cursor in TexShop? I use a dark background and the black cursor is barely visible.

Comment: Are you using dark mode?

Comment: I was using a customised mode, based on the Dark Mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please take a look at the Insertion color in the Source section of TeXShop-> >Preferences Themes tab. YOu might want to make the Flash color the same as your background too so it does look like it's blinking.

Comment: This perfectly solves the problem, gracias :)